# How to assign global variable inside of an asynchronous function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Console logging the **lat** returns **undefined**, while I want to assign the value of **position.coords.latitude** to it. What is the problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var lat, lon;

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      lat=position.coords.latitude;
      lon=position.coords.longitude;
    });
    console.log(lat);
  }
});
```

Comment: maybe `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` not happens. create an `else` case, and check  that.

Comment: have you tried putting the `console.log` inside the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` ?

Comment: `lat=position.coords.latitude;` this line is not working

Comment: @Chinito yes it returns inside

Comment: @Sagar V1 it is working without any problems except getting **lat** outside

Comment: and is it still undefined?

Comment: @vaso123 I tried it works

Comment: @Chinito no, it is a number value

Comment: !!! I think it is asynchrous assignment problem, but can't figure out how solve myself

Comment: then it is working. nothings wrong with it. because it is an asynchronous function

Comment: @Chinito I want to know how to wait for asynchronous function before geting access of returned value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't log there, you must need callback function to achieve your goal

```
<script>
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
      x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
   }
 }
function showPosition(position) {
  console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +" Longitude: "          + position.coords.longitude)
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: While I learned something from reading your code, it doesnt answer my question. I want to get value of **position.coords.latitude** outside

Comment: You can do like this only function showPosition(position) {
  lat=position.coords.latitude;
}

Comment: You can assign value to your global variable only in callback function

Answer (score 0):

use callback function
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var lat, lon;

```
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        lat=position.coords.latitude;
        lon=position.coords.longitude;
        callbackFunction();
     });
   }

   function callbackFuncton(){
      console.log(lat);
      //you can use your lat and lon here
   }
});
```