# Global var is undefined outside function, Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm trying to store a variable inside a function into a global variable.

But the global variable outside of the function stays undefined.

Code snippet:

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
}

var latitude;
var longitude; 

function showPosition(position) {
x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
"<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
 latitude = position.coords.latitude                   
 longitude = position.coords.longitude                 
 console.log(longitude);    // var longitude is set here 
}
console.log(longitude);   // var longitude is undefined here
```

I want to use the variable outside of the function too, how can I fix this?

Comment: You need to execute the function. What is x and where do you define position?

Comment: Function not executed, and your code snippet seems to be incomplete

Comment: Given that these are geocoordinates, I'm guessing that the real problem is [how to return the response from an asynchronous call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Comment: The geolocation operation is **asynchronous**. Your `showPosition()` function will be called only when the operation (the underlying network request) has completed.

Answer (score -1):

Refer this code

```
<script>
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
      x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
   }
 }
function showPosition(position) {
  console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +" Longitude: "          + position.coords.longitude)
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: ??, yeah thats the original code

Comment: This is not original code

Comment: Check this link this is original question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946625/how-to-assign-global-variable-inside-of-an-asynchronous-function-in-javascript/42946856#42946856)

Comment: You can not console or use outside the asynchronous function instead you can set result as a hidden variable and then find whenever you want